# Comparing two values Var to obtain a masked list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to get a list of objects based on 'un-selected' values in a ListBox

I tried this but no joy :

```
var masked = storedInvestments.Where(i => i.attachedCards.Any(c => c.ID != selected.All(x=>x.ID));
```

basically look through storedInvestments and get back a list of those that not selected in a ListBox control that lists all Investments either selected or not.

I can't help feeling this is a join thing.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Paul above for setting me in the right path, 
the actual code is as follows:

```
var masked = storedInvestments.Where(i => i.attachedCards.Any(c => !selected.Contains(i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

how about?

`var masked = storedInvestments.Where(i => i.attachedCards.Any(c => !selected.Contains(c.ID));`

Comment: Thanks Paul , pointed me in the right direction, answer below